# access github api with github token from action always got "Bad credentials"

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I tried to valid wheather a request came from the github action.

So I create a workflow:

```
name: test

on:
#  workflow_dispatch:
  push:

permissions: read-all

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: test token
        run: |
          curl "http://xxxxx/test_token?github_token=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

and the server print the github token:

`token is: ghs_xxxxxx482tJb`

then I use this token to access github api by curl, but it always get `Bad credentials`

the api I tried:

1. `https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/repo_name/pages`
2. `https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/repo_name/actions/workflows`
3. `https://api.github.com/installation/repositories`

and request example:

```
$> curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ghs_xxxxxsOUCk482tJb"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/ky-infrastructure/tool-script/actions/workflows
```

response:

```
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

Comment: The token expires when the job finishes.

Comment: thx for reminder! I compeletely forget about this!